# ASP.NET removing DropDownList item inside repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-select, asprepeater

I don't know if I am allowed to post such a specific issue here.

The scenario is that I have a Product that has a many to many relationship with Category.
Means one product may belong to multiple categories and a category may have multiple products. Now on the form I have provide a dropdown along with a button that says add another category and when I click on that button another dropdown should appear below that first dropdown. and the selected item of the previous dropdown must be remove from the dropdown items.

Below is my code of the dropdown's repeater and the two buttons mentioned.

```
    protected void btnAddAnotherCategory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<int> selectedIndices = new List<int>();
        foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptCategories.Items)
        {
            if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                DropDownList ddlCategory = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("ddlCategory");
                int selectedIndex = ddlCategory.SelectedIndex;
                selectedIndices.Add(selectedIndex);
            }
        }
        ViewState["objSelectedIndices"] = selectedIndices;
        rptCategories_DataSource("add", false);
    }

    protected void btnRemoveCategory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<int> selectedIndices = new List<int>();
        foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptCategories.Items)
        {
            if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                DropDownList ddlCategory = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("ddlCategory");
                int selectedIndex = ddlCategory.SelectedIndex;
                selectedIndices.Add(selectedIndex);
            }
        }
        ViewState["objSelectedIndices"] = selectedIndices;
        rptCategories_DataSource("remove", false);
    }

    protected void rptCategories_DataSource(string editCommand, bool pageLoad)
    {
        switch (editCommand)
        {
            case "add":
                if (ViewState["categoriesCount"] == null)
                {
                    List<Category> count = new List<Category>();
                    count.Add(new Category());
                    ViewState["categoriesCount"] = count;
                }
                if (!pageLoad)
                {
                    List<Category> count = (List<Category>)ViewState["categoriesCount"];
                    count.Add(new Category());
                    ViewState["categoriesCount"] = count;
                }
                List<Category> objCategories = (List<Category>)ViewState["categoriesCount"];
                objCategories = objCategories.Where(x => x.StatusID != 3).ToList();
                rptCategories.DataSource = objCategories;
                rptCategories.DataBind();
                break;
            case "remove":
                if (((List<Category>)ViewState["categoriesCount"]).Count > 1)
                {
                    List<Category> count = (List<Category>)ViewState["categoriesCount"];
                    count.Remove(count.Last());
                    count = count.Where(x => x.StatusID != 3).ToList();
                    ViewState["categoriesCount"] = count;
                    rptCategories.DataSource = count;
                    rptCategories.DataBind();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    protected void rptCategories_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Category objCategory = (Category)e.Item.DataItem;

        DropDownList ddlCategory = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddlCategory");
        ddlCategory.DataSource = new CategoryBLL().GetAllCategoriesWithStatus();
        ddlCategory.DataTextField = "Name";
        ddlCategory.DataValueField = "ID";
        ddlCategory.DataBind();

        if (objCategory.CategoryID != null)
            ddlCategory.SelectedValue = objCategory.CategoryID.ToString();

        if (ViewState["objSelectedIndices"] != null)
        {
            List<int> objSelectedIndices = (List<int>)ViewState["objSelectedIndices"];
            if (objSelectedIndices.Count > e.Item.ItemIndex)
                ddlCategory.SelectedIndex = objSelectedIndices.ElementAt(e.Item.ItemIndex);
        }

        if (e.Item.ItemIndex < ((List<Category>)rptCategories.DataSource).Count - 1)
        {
            ddlCategory.Enabled = false;
        }

        btnAddAnotherCategory.Visible = true;
        btnRemoveCategory.Visible = true;
        if (rptCategories.Items.Count < 1)
        {
            btnRemoveCategory.Visible = false;
        }
        if (rptCategories.Items.Count >= new CategoryBLL().GetAllCategoriesWithStatus().Count - 1)
        {
            btnAddAnotherCategory.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

The StatusID mentioned in the code is to determine the deleted products as I am not ACTUALLY deleting the Product rather only setting its StatusID

Now the problem is that my code works fine with the above statements but as you can see it does not remove the selected items from the dropdown. The dropdown's are required to be populated from a single table everytime. The tricky part is removing the selecteditems in the previous repeateritems dropdownlist.
Any solution would be welcomed.